# Insert Method infinite loop in a doublylinkedlist

Tags: loops, while-loop, linked-list, infinite, doubly-linked-list

I may just be entirely ignorant to what is happening here but i've looked over it a million times and i'm sure it is something obvious but my insert method infinitely loops due to the while loop. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code..

```
 package dcjaniszewskiOL4;



    public class DoublyLinkedList<T extends Comparable> {
    private class Node<T>
    {
        private T data;
        private Node<T> next;
        private Node<T> prev;

        private Node(T d){
            data=d;
            next=null;
            prev=null;
        }
        private Node( T d, Node<T> pref, Node<T> nref){
            data=d;
            prev=pref;
            next=nref;
        }


    }

    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> current;
    private int size;

    public DoublyLinkedList(){
       head = new Node<T>(null,null,null);
       current=head.next;
       size=0;
    }

    public DoublyLinkedList(DoublyLinkedList<T> i){

    }

    public void insert (T d){
      Node<T> ptr, trav, prev;



      prev=null;
      begin();
      trav=head.next;

      if(empty()){
        head.next = new Node<T>(d,head,head);

    }


      while(trav!=null){

        System.out.println(trav.data);
        prev=trav;
        advance();
        trav=current;

    }
      ptr = new Node<T> (d, prev,head);

      if(prev==null){
        head.next=ptr;
        head.prev=ptr;
    }
      else{
        prev.next=ptr;
        current.prev=ptr;
    }
    size++;
    }

    public void remove(T d) throws ListEmptyException, NotInListException{
    Node<T> tmp = head;

      if(head.next==null){
        throw new ListEmptyException("List is empty on Remove");
    }
      while(tmp!=null){
        if(tmp.data.equals(d)){
            tmp.prev.next=tmp.next;
            tmp.next.prev=tmp.prev;
            size--;
        }else{
            tmp=tmp.next;
            if(tmp==null){
                throw new NotInListException("Item is not in the list");
            }
        }
    }
    }
    public void begin(){
      current=head.next;
    }
    public void advance(){
      current.prev = current;
      current=current.next;

    }
    public void retreat(){

      current.next=current;
      current=current.prev;
    }
    public T current() throws ListEmptyException{
      if(current==null){
        throw new ListEmptyException("List is empty");
      }else{
      return current.data;
      }
    }
      public boolean end(){
      boolean end = false;
      if(current==null){
        end=true;
      }else{
        end=false;
      }
      return end;
    }
    public boolean empty(){
      boolean empty = false;
      if(size()==0){
        empty=true;
      }else{
        empty=false;
      }
    return empty;
    }
    public int size(){
      return size;
    }
    }
```

Comment: When you ask other people to read your code, please use spaces. Such as `if(size() == 0) {`.

Comment: Why are you setting `current.prev` to `current` in `advance()`? Calling `var pointer = current; while (pointer.prev == pointer) { pointer = pointer.prev } ` after that will infinitely loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ptr = new Node<T> (d, null,null);
trav=head;
while (trav.next!= null)
{
    trav = trav.next;
}
trav.next = ptr;
ptr.prev = trav;
```

Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: I know this is so late, but I figured out the issue soon after I made this post but I didn't want you to think I was leaving you hanging so sorry about that ! Thanks for the help.